# What function is the opposite of diff in R?

Tags: r, vector

I know this is a stupid question, but is there a function in R that is the opposite of diff, where you can add consecutive pairs in a vector. I.e. if you had the original vector 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, you would get back 3, 5, 7, 11 (1+2, 2+3, 3+4, 4+5)?

Comment: Have you tried `cumsum`? It's imperfect, since calling `diff` loses one datum, and unless you know that the original started with `1`, there's no way to safely infer it.

Comment: For example, `vec <- 1:5`, then you can recreate it with `cumsum(c(vec[1], diff(vec)))`.

Comment: Not a function, but simple is `x[-n] + x[-1]` where `n <- length(x)`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use filter function.just ensure you have the right felter/kernel for the lag. Ie `lag=1` in the `diff` function use `filter=c(1,1)` in the `filter` function. :

```
x <-1:5
filter(x, c(1,1), sides = 1)
```

Comment: ... and wrap an `as.numeric` around it to strip off the `"ts"` class.

Comment: If `lag =2` use `filter =(1,0,1)`

Answer (score 3):

Here are some possibilities:

```
rowSums(embed(x, 2))
## [1] 3 5 7 9

x |> embed(2) |> rowSums() # same but with pipes
## [1] 3 5 7 9

head(x, -1) + tail(x, -1)
## [1] 3 5 7 9

diff(cumsum(c(0, x)), 2)
## [1] 3 5 7 9

c(ts(x) + lag(ts(x)))
## [1] 3 5 7 9

library(zoo)
rollsum(x, 2)
## [1] 3 5 7 9

# Since this is a linear operation it has a matrix M
M <- apply(diag(length(x)), 2, rollsum, 2)
c(M %*% x)
## [1] 3 5 7 9

# Take sub or super diagonal of the outer sum
out <- outer(x, x, `+`)
out[row(out) == col(out) - 1]
## [1] 3 5 7 9
```

### Note

```
x <- 1:5
```